# Different PHP version for different PhpStorm scopes

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

Is it possible to have different **PHP language level** and **CLI interpreter** for different project scopes in PhpStorm 2023.1?

I have a project like this:

```
project
\_project1
  \_docker
  \_src
\_project2
  \_docker
  \_src
\_mysql
  \_docker
  \_data
\_rabbitmq
  \_docker
  \_data
\_docker-compose.yml
```

- Project1 runs on its container with PHP 8.1.
- Project2 runs on its container with PHP 7.4.
- Mysql and rabbitmq are containers used by both *project1* and *project2*.

I like this configuration because of with one group of containers and one network I have an exact copy of my production environment.

I created two different scopes, one for *project1* and another for *project2*. Everything works fine when searching, navigating to usage or declarations, but I can't find a way to instruct PhpStorm to use different PHP versions and CLI interpreters for the two scopes, and I have to manually switch every time I jump from a source to another.

Comment: JetBrains are at least working on supporting this type of project, but I don't know if that particular setting is implemented yet: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/#version-2023-1-support-for-multi-composer-and-multi-vendor-projects

Comment: Thanks for the link, very useful. Right now out of the box also git submodules are working smoothly, the only thing really missing is the ability to address different container for different scopes, also for quality check tools like php Cs-Fixer

Comment: Here is a similar but unresolved yet feature request:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-57315/Ability-to-set-PHP-language-level-per-directory